# ReactJS with Firebase - Is it possible to log in as a user for troubleshooting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using ReactJS with Firebase authentication with email and password. I'm looking for a way to log in as a user based on email or user uid in order to troubleshoot some problems - for example, when customer says he paid for a subscription but his account hasn't been updated, etc. Is there a way to manage this kind of an admin access? I didn't find much information in the official documentation and will appreciate your suggestions. What are the best practices in this case?

That's how I create and retrieve users:

```
export const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

  const signIn = (email, password) => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
      setLoading(false)
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ createUser, user, signIn }}>
      {!loading && children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

To retrieve user:

```
const { user } = UserAuth();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement this, you're going to end up writing a substantial amount of both frontend and backend code.  I will give you just an overview since a full explanation is beyond the scope of a question on Stack Overflow.

1. You're going have to implement some sort of backend API endpoint that provides an ID token for a user that you identify, ideally by providing a UID as input.  Use the Firebase Admin SDK to [create a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) for the user and pass it back to the admin user using the frontend.  You should secure this endpoint so that ordinary users can't do this, otherwise you are implementing a huge security hole.
2. On your frontend, [using that custom token, sign in as that user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) with `signInWithCustomToken()`. The frontend will now be signed in using the same credentials as the user that was provided in #1.  When you do this, the prior signed in user (the admin user) will be signed out.  If you want to revert to the original user, they will have to choose to sign out of your app, then back in again with the admin user.

If you don't like the idea of having only one user signed in at the same time like this, then you will need to write a whole lot more code to initialize and maintain two different Firebase app objects, and use them separately where the normal and admin users privileges are required.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Doug Stevenson! This is a great starting point for me, I didn't even know this approach was possible. I'm going to explore it now and I'll get back to you if I have any questions. Many thanks!